# PHPMailer does not work with gmail

Tags: php, ssl, gmail, wampserver, smtpd

after trying to let my PHPMailer run with gmail for some days I have to find some help here. I read nearly everything I could find here or in Google but none of the ideas helped until now. 
I am using 
* Windows 7 Home Basic 
* Wampserver 2.2 with PHP vers. PHP Version 5.4.3
  all necessary extensions are set up like e. g. php_opensll
* PHPMailer 5.2.9

This is the script I am using:

```
<?php
//require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';                                              // <<== I have tried this also - no sucess

require 'class-phpmailer.php';
require "class-smtp.php"; //"PHPMailerAutoload.php";
// $mail->PluginDir //WB, 30 Nov 2014:omited if all files from phpmailer are in the same folder
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
// I have tried both - TLS and SSL - with the required ports ==>> both are not working 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
// or try these settings (worked on XAMPP and WAMP):
//$mail->Port = 587;
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->Username = "wie****@gmail.com";      //my password ==>> works if I make a login oline to my account
$mail->Password = "*************";  //my password ==>> works if I make a login oline to my account

$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                      // <<== enables SMTP debug information (for testing)

$mail->IsHTML(true);    // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.

$mail->From = "wie****@gmail.com";                  //my gmail mail account
$mail->FromName = "My Name";

$mail->addAddress("art******@yahoo.com","art******"); //my yahoo mail account
//$mail->addAddress("user.2@gmail.com","User 2");

//$mail->addCC("user.3@ymail.com","User 3");
//$mail->addBCC("user.4@in.com","User 4");

$mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
$mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

I am trying already any variation I could found in the net but nothing works.

I have tried it with
- 'PHPMailerAutoload.php' and 'class.phpmailer.php' as required class
- “$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';” and “$mail->Port = 465;”
 as well as with 
- “$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';” and “$mail->Port = 587;”

Here are the debugging log-files:

> Debug-Log when using TLS with port 587
>
> SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP cq6sm24503844pad.30 -
>   gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service,
>   [121.54.112.183] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 SMTP
>   -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [121.54.112.183] 250-SIZE 35882577
>   250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
>   OAUTHBEARER 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250
>   SMTPUTF8 SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14
>   Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.
>   534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754
>   cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Flushed
>   cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER:530-5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from
>   server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp The following From address failed:
>   wiedeia@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp
>
> SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530
>   5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp Message was not sent PHPMailer Error: The
>   following From address failed: wiedeia@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted
>   from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp
>
> SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530
>   5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp
>
> SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530
>   5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 cq6sm24503844pad.30 - gsmtp
>
> Debug-Log when using SSL with port 465
>
> SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP kj9sm24304154pbc.37 -
>   gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service,
>   [121.54.112.183] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
>   XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>   250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 SMTP -> ERROR: Password not
>   accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser
>   and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754
>   kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Flushed
>   kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER:530-5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from
>   server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp The following From address failed:
>   wiedeia@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp
>
> SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530
>   5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp Message was not sent PHPMailer Error: The
>   following From address failed: wiedeia@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted
>   from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
>   kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp
>
> SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530
>   5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp
>
> SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530
>   5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 kj9sm24304154pbc.37 - gsmtp

I checked the links gmail is offering with the debugging. But nothing works. When I log into my account on the web with the same information for user and password it works.

I also followed the advices I found in the net to allow less secure apps. Also I allowed the access to my account with Google using the link https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Then I checked the ports with a port scanner both ports are mentioned as closed. But I guess they will be opened when requested by an application. A check with telnet smtp.gmail.com has been successful.

I tried the script also without running any antivirus and firewall – no result.

Slowly slowly I run a little bit mad with this issue. May be someone can help me here.

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Arthur, it is tuff to answer with out knowing the correct details. I mean, if you have two factor authentication enabled, you'll need to setup an application specific password to use in place of your email account's password.

You can generate an application specific password by following these instructions: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Then set $mail->Password to your application specific password.

Random Work Around: some times, we have to enable the two step verification for some accounts then it will work (I did not know the correct reasons behind it, but this works for some accounts)

But from outside, Here are some hints to troubleshoot this: 
1) check again [You said U checked it] SSL correctly configured on your PHP (module that handle it isn't installed by default on PHP. You have to check your configuration in phph.ini). 
2) check if your firewall let outgoing calls to the required port (here 465 or 587). Use telnet to do so. If the port isn't opened, you'll then require some support from sysdmin to setup the config. 
3) Open this https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?hl=en and select follow the instructions,google servers blocks any attempts from unknown servers so once you click on captcha check every thing will be fine

I hope you'll sort this out quickly!

Comment: HI - and many tanks for the answer. 
I told already in my post that I used telnet to check the ports. Also that I closed any firewall and anti virus. And yes I have checked proper the setting of php.ini and also the php extensions. And I read all the google stuff from the debug log. But it did not help.

Comment: what about the two step verification? if not enabled, just enable it and try it. As i said it is just a random workaround.

Comment: Thanks again - but as I wrote in the second comment below here this is not an option for me. I am in Asia on an small island and here we do not have a signal all the time! I think it has to work also without it - or? Have a nice day Andreas